# Merge excel files in R

Tags: r, excel, merge

I imported 8 Excel files into r and the content of the files are the same.

Now I want to merge these 8 files into one. I used the function merge.
Here is my code:

```
> merge1 = merge(Data1.1, Data1.2, all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)
> merge2 = merge(merge1, Data2.1, all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)
> merge3 = merge(merge2, Data2.2, all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)
> merge4 = merge(merge3, Data3.1, all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)
```

Somehow R didn´t took all the rows from Data3.1 . The rows from merge 3 are 1.913.573. The rows from Data3.1 are in total 479.273. The rows in merge 4 are just 1.919.232 instead of 1.913.573 + 479.273 = 2.392.846.

Why r didn´t took all of the rows from Data3.1?

Thank u guys!!!!

Comment: Without specifying `by = `, the `merge` function joins the columns with common names by default. You probably have some common columns and it is using those to join. Without knowing the data structure this is just a guess though

Comment: sounds like you are trying row-bind, instead of merge,.. Perhaps just `rbind(Data1.1,Data1.2,Data2.1,<etc>)`

Comment: One possibility is your records are being dropped because `merge()` defaults to no duplicates (`no.dups=TRUE`). If your goal is to append the records from 1.2 to the end of 1.1, check out the function `dplyr::bind_rows()`

Comment: Alternatively you could use `purrr` such that you do not have to load each dataset individually, e.g. `list.files("data/", full.names = T, pattern = "\\.xlsx") %>% 
  purrr::map_dfr(readxl::read_excel)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have same column names and same number of columns in all 8 files (as it looks like since you said 'content of the files are same'), you should use rbind function.

```
Newdf <- rbind(Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4, Data5, Data6, Data7, Data8)
```

Note that R will throw an error in either of the following scenarios:

The data frames don’t have the same number of columns.
The data frames don’t have the same column names.

More information can be found here:
https://www.statology.org/rbind-in-r/